# Why are my arguments ignored only when passed with `subprocess.call`?

Tags: python, shell, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to call the command

```
& 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code' --folder-uri='vscode-remote://ssh-remote+SERVER.domain.net/home/USERNAME/Dropbox/Projects/PROJECTNAME'
```

from a Python script with

```py
codepath = os.path.join(os.environ['LocalAppData'], 'Programs', 'Microsoft VS Code', 'bin', 'code')
path_parts = (
    "--folder-uri='vscode-remote://ssh-remote+SERVER.domain.net/home/USERNAME/Dropbox/Projects/PROJECTNAME'",
)
subprocess.call([codepath] + list(path_parts), shell=True)
```

If I put that first command into an interactive powershell, vscode opens fine, (modulo replacing the upper-case placeholders with actually existing things).

If I do

```
"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --folder-uri="vscode-remote://ssh-remote+SERVER.tomsb.net/home/USERNAME/Dropbox/Projects/PROJECTNAME"
```

in an interactive windows Command Prompt, it opens.

However, the python code just opens vscode as if no arguments were given (or as if a garbled local path was given--I *can* open local directories by providing them as the second entry in the first `call` argument.

How can I debug this??

Comment: If you're using `shell=True`, I think you can just pass the command as a single string, instead of making a list of args.  Try that.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah, that works, if I `subprocess.call('"C:\...\bin\code" --folder-uri="...ALSO HAS SPACES..."')` (that, is, double-quote the strings with spaces). Wish I knew why it didn't work with the civilized list-of-commandline-parts way, but you could make your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: With `shell=True`: *"If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself."* - so in your example, `path_parts` is being passed as an arg to the shell, not to VS Code. Does your code not work with the default `shell=False`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the arguments as a list, try passing them as string:

```py
codepath = os.path.join(os.environ['LocalAppData'], 'Programs', 'Microsoft VS Code', 'bin', 'code')
path_parts = "--folder-uri='vscode-remote://ssh-remote+SERVER.domain.net/home/USERNAME/Dropbox/Projects/PROJECTNAME'"
subprocess.call(f'"{codepath}" {path_parts}', shell=True)
```

This should pass the entire command as a single string to the shell, which should correctly interpret the arguments.